# Magento 2 how to interact with products grid collection

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I'm trying to find the best way to modify products collection for products grid in admin. In particular, to add additional filter to the collection. I don't want to override the grid's block to achieve that. Looks like I'm stuck and cant find a point to start using DI in this case. Also, I can't find any event for loading grid collection as it was in Magento 1.x 
If someone has experience in this I would be very appreciate for any info.

Comment: I'm not sure we're really there in terms of separation of concerns, but Magento2 is so different from Magento1 that I feel a need to separate the two entirely. Questions, inquiries... whatever - it all belongs somewhere else as this is an entirely different beast

Comment: P.s. I raised the concern here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/541/where-do-magento2-questions-belong feel free to chime in if you want!

Comment: @ReidBlomquist it clearly says Magento 2 questions are allowed.

Comment: My fault; didn't realize this was the case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to create "before" plugin for `Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid::setCollection` and make with collection all that you want.

Comment: Yeah, found the same solution. Anyway, thanks for the advice.